# How to recover file?

Tags: files

I have recently been working on an Arduino sketch for school. Today at lunch I was working on it, around two hours later I open the file again and it is blank. Is there any thing I can do to recover it? I already check my /Root/tmp and it is not there. If anyone could help that would be great

Comment: Check in `File` > `Open Recent` in Arduino IDE

Comment: Already tried that I can find the file it is just blank. Thanks for the suggestion though